# Vercel blocking google from indexing website

Tags: next.js, vercel, google-developers-console

I have deployed my Next.js app on [Vercel](https://vercel.com) and when inspecting my website in the Google console, I see that crawl requests by Google are met with a 401 unauthorized error. This also reflects in my deployment logs console as shown below:

[image: deployment logs screenshot]

The url I'm trying to parse has already been added to the `publicRoutes` in my middleware file and I do not know why it is being blocked. I also tried adjusting the middleware and looking into what may have caused it but could not find anything.

Comment: Definitely more information is needed here. Is your application blocking all the routes or some specific routes?

Comment: The middleware file defines public routes using clerk is as follows

    publicRoutes: ["/", "/api/webhook", "/sign-up", "sign-in"]

Comment: robots.txt allows everythign

Comment: Did you require any form of token or cookies? If yes, you have to send them, or make your routes unprotected

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I came across this solution somewhere, I can't remember the exact location because I had about 50 tabs open trying to resolve this issue. I commented out everything (even the publicRoutes) and added the following:

```
import { withClerkMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export default withClerkMiddleware((req: NextRequest) => {
  return NextResponse.next();
});

export const config = {
  matcher: "/((?!_next/image|_next/static|favicon.ico).*)",
};
```

`withClerkMiddleware` has been deprecated, but it has made my site discoverable, and I'm currently waiting for it to get indexed.